# CSS Color for Text Not Working in All Browsers

Tags: css, colors

I have an accordion drop down button that I want the "+" to appear in red. It's displaying properly on my desktop PC computer in Chrome browser, but when I open the website on my mac using Chrome, or in firefox, the red color isn't coming through.

```
.accordion {
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  line-height:1.2em;
  font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
  color:hsl(0, 0%, 34%);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


.accordion:after {
  content: '\0020 \02795';
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color:#FF0000 !important;

}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796 \0020";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */

}
```

[image]

When I inspect the button it has the right code but it is still not showing red.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of this weird hack:

```
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0 0 0 red;
```

Or just use the UTF-8 character '+'

Answer (score 0):

how about trying to put the ::after content to “+”.
If nothing works and you are using JS to handle the .active class process, just add a span contains the plus character and change its content to minus when active.